# Motion equation for particle in potential field with const $L$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy

Particle with mass $m$ moves in potential $U(r) = br^3$ write the equation of motion for const $L$

---

What i tried:

Can i just use :

$$
F=-\nabla U(r) = -3br^2 \rightarrow ma = F
$$
Yet im not sure that this is the way to do it and i dont use $L$.

Anither way i thought is:

$$
E=0.5mr'^2 + 0.5\frac{L^2}{mr^2} + U(r)
$$
Isolating $r'$ getting:
$$
\frac{dr}{r^2\sqrt{2m\frac{E-U}{L^2}-1/r^2}} = d \phi
$$
Substituting for $U$ i get quite complicated differential equation.

Directions?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Comment: I didnt show enough effort? I dont understand what have i done wrong

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right way!
$$\phi = \int \frac{Ldr/r^2}{\sqrt{2m[E-U(r)]-L^2/r^2}}+\text{constant} $$
The fact is, if the potential given by $U\sim r^n$ then the exact solution exist for $n=2,-1,-2$. The power $n=3$ can only be written as elliptical integral.

---

Edit : The equation of motion of the system for any system given by
$$f(t,r,\dot{r},\cdots )=0$$
In the OP's problem, One finds
$$\frac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2+\frac{L^2}{2mr^2}+br^3=E$$
$$\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\frac{L}{mr^2}$$
These are equations of motion, and they can't be solved for an explicit solutions but you can solve them numerically.
Suppose we are given $(r_0,t_0,\phi_0)$ as initial condition then
we can write
$$r(t_0+\Delta t)=r(t_0)+\dot{r}(t_0)\Delta t$$
$$\phi(t_0+\Delta t)=\phi(t_0)+\dot{\phi}(t_0)\Delta t$$

Comment: Thank you, so i cant solve the integral, but does that describes the equation of motion? It does not seem like newtons second law....?

Comment: Yeah, it's doing. The equation of motion means, You need to find $\phi(t)$ and $r(t)$ which you did. It's another matter that in this case there isn't any explicit form but you can always solve these numerically.

Comment: Thanks, Can you explain me alitttle more why its describe the equation of motion? Because its describe the position of the body as a function of t?

Comment: @Alon I have added the little explanation.